# Joda and moving the program/ having the program on multiple computers

Tags: java, jodatime

I have downloaded and added Joda to my program. My question is: if I move the program to another computer do I have to do anything to do with joda? (does the other computer have to have it "installed" or something?) also how would I find out the amount of time between a certain date and the date now? Would it just be like a normal maths equation (date out - date now) or is there something else.?

Thanks and/or sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: What computer language did you write your program in?

Comment: Sorry left out tag. I am writing in java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is platform independent language so no matter if you write your code in one machine,
it will surely be run as same with output in another machine.

**Regarding Joda Time:**

The Joda Time can give you time in seconds/hours/minutes..

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Between calculation logic to calculate time in hours:

```
hours = Hours.hoursBetween(new LocalDateTime(DateTime1), new LocalDateTime(DateTime2)).getHours();
```

You need to parse the current date for the date object to get it in DateTime format.

Comment: Just to add to this answer: yes, your Java code will run on another machine (that has the JRE), but by default - your JAR will not be packaged with Joda. This means that you'll get a `NoClassDefFoundError` unless you package Joda inside of your JAR, or distribute it with your jar and an appropriate classloader